# как сделать кликабельным imageView во время анимации

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сделать зацикленную Translate анимацию imageView из рэндомных координат в рэндомные которая бы останавливалась по клику на imageView - Но Работает только при клике на первоначальную позицию imageView. Можно как то это реализовать таким образом ? или каким то другим? ) Заранее извиняюсь если вопрос глупый - первый опыт на java 
Код:

```
public void animGo(){
    img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.anim1);
    xs = (int)( Math.random()*(max-min)+min);
    xe = (int)( Math.random()*(max-min)+min);
    ys = (int)( Math.random()*(max-min)+min);
    ye = (int)( Math.random()*(max-min)+min);
    final TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(xs, xe, ys, ye);
    anim.setDuration(3000);
    //anim.setFillEnabled(true);
    anim.setFillAfter(false);
    img1.startAnimation(anim);
    img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            anim.cancel();
        }
    });

    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            animGo();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Анимация это смещение картинки относительно его изначального места, тебе нужно смещать именно сам элемент ImageView по координатам.и программно анимировать.